# polymorphism functions python

Tags: python, polymorphism

let's say I have A module 'utils.py',
and I have some functions on this module I would like to executeing.
the problem is - I know for sure all the function which start with 'important' have the 'first_arg' on their signature, but I don't know for sure those functions have 'second_arg' and 'third_arg'.
what is the best way to handle this case? (from utils.py or from runner.py)
one possible solution is to add **kwargs to every function but it seem's to me like an ugly solution. my prefer solution is to handle it on the runner.py moudle.

utils.py:

```
def important_func_one(first_arg):
    #do something

def important_func_two(first_arg, second_arg):
    #do something

def important_func_two(first_arg, second_arg, third_arg):
    #do something

def _private_function():
    #so something
```

and I have another moudle 'runner.py'

```
import utils

def __main__:
    first_value = 'first value'
    second_value = 'second value'
    third_value = 'third value'

    for func_name, func_value in moudle.__dict__.items()
        if name.startwith('important'):
           func_value(first_value, second_value, third_value )
```

Comment: Normalizing argument forms will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If the missing link is getting the number of positional params at runtime, then this should work:

```
def f(a):
    print(a)


def g(a, b):
    print(a, b)


functions = {"f": f, "g": g}
args = [0, 1]

for _, func in functions.items():
    num_of_args = func.__code__.co_argcount
    func(*args[:num_of_args])

# output:
0
0 1
```

That being said, I think that an altogether different design approach would make things easier for you.

Comment: which kind of design for exmaple?

Comment: It depends. Since I don't know the implementation of the `important` functions, it's hard to tell. But I suppose a quick win would be to make each of them accept a single iterable param.